# use python script in shell (like fabric)

Tags: python, bash

I want to make a script that has a lot of options and easy to use. For example, to use the script, I normally have to type:

```
workon my_env
python my_script.py -o1 option1 -o2 option2
```

But how to make this easy like the way fabric does? Like:

```
my_script -O1 option1 -o2 option2
```

Comment: for command line use, the argparse standard lib is also quite useful, providing awesome facilities to parse command line arguments super easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your script start with the line: `#!/usr/bin/env python`
Or, depending on your version: `#!/usr/bin/env python3.3`

Then you must make your script executable with a `chmod`, and it should work like you want!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add #!/usr/bin/python (this should be the first line) to your script file and make it executable.